# Why laravel create method return Data missing from carbon, but using new model() works

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, php-carbon

in IdentityController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{ 
    $req = $request->all();
    $req['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
    $input = PersonalData::updateOrCreate($req);
}
```

this return

> "Data missing"
>   C:\Project\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php

but if i use this, it works

```
public function store(Request $request)
{ 
    $input= new PersonalData;
    $input->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $input->save();
}
```

can someone tell me why this happened? thanks before

Comment: What do you send with your request?

Comment: address, phone, birth_date, etc

Comment: your question is missing some pieces request input, the exact error and what you expect it to do, there is a reason no one has answered it as it is pretty straight forward.